# Python Tkinter Radiobutton returns value for wrong instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple quiz with multiple pages and radio buttons using Tkinter. I am at the stage where I now need to get the chosen radio buttons to formulate some kind of response.

When I press the testing "press me" button, it is supposed to output the IntVar for the Radiobuttons in the Question on the current page. However, it gets the IntVar for Page2, even when on Page1.

If I only have one page, it works as expected.

```
import tkinter as tk

#a single frame with a question and multiple options
class Question(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *options, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *options, **kwargs)
        global self1
        self1 = self

    def Configure(notneeded, *options, **keywords):
        print("-" * 40)
        questionframe=tk.Frame(self1)
        questionframe.pack(side="top", fill="x")        
        for kw in keywords:
            if kw == "question":
                tk.Label(questionframe, text=keywords[kw]).pack(anchor=tk.W)
                print(keywords[kw])
        print("-" * 40)
        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self1)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        global v
        v = tk.IntVar() #variable for keeping track of radiobuttons
        Buttons = []
        i = 1
        for option in options:
            b = tk.Radiobutton(buttonframe, text=option, variable=v, 
value=i)
            b.pack(anchor=tk.W)
            Buttons.append(b)
            i += 1
            print(option)
        return Buttons

    #return the index of the selected radiobutton (starts from 1)
    def GetSelectedIndex(notneeded):
        return v.get()

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def ButtonPress():
            print("Selected Option:", q1.GetSelectedIndex())
        global q1
        q1 = Question(self)
        q1.Configure("Car", "Minecart", "Riding a spider", "Flight",
            question="How would you prefer to get around?")
        q1.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(self, command=ButtonPress, text="press me - 1").pack()
   def GetSelectedIndex(notneeded):
        return q1.GetSelectedIndex()

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def ButtonPress():
            print("Selected Option:", q1.GetSelectedIndex())
        global q1
        q1 = Question(self)
        q1.Configure("Day", "Night",
        question="Do you prefer day or night time?")
        q1.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(self, command=ButtonPress, text="press me - 2").pack()
   def GetSelectedIndex(notneeded):
        return q1.GetSelectedIndex()

CurrentPage = 0
MaxPages = 1
def ChangePage(amount):
    global CurrentPage
    CurrentPage += amount
    CurrentPage = sorted((0, CurrentPage, MaxPages))[1]
    print("Current Page: " + str(CurrentPage))
    return CurrentPage

class MainView(tk.Frame):     
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def On_Back():
            ChangePage(-1)
            Pages[CurrentPage].lift()
        def On_Next():
            ChangePage(1)
            Pages[CurrentPage].lift()
        def GetP1Value():
            print("Selected Option:", Pages[0].GetSelectedIndex())

        #the correct value is output when Page2(self) is removed
        Pages = [Page1(self), Page2(self)]

        Frame_Buttons = tk.Frame(self)
        Frame_Buttons.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", expand=False)
        Button_Next = tk.Button(Frame_Buttons, text="Next", 
command=On_Next).pack(side="right")
        Button_Back = tk.Button(Frame_Buttons, text="Back", 
command=On_Back).pack(side="right")
        tk.Button(Frame_Buttons, text="get page 1", 
command=GetP1Value).pack(side="right")
        Frame_Pages = tk.Frame(self)
        Frame_Pages.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        for page in Pages:
            page.place(in_=Frame_Pages, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        Pages[0].show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("300x300")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the use of global variables to track the pages and the questions. In your Page1 and Page2 classes, you declare the global variable with the same name, and you overwrite the `self1` value when you instantiate subsequent pages. Especially given that you are using class-based structure for your app, the global variables should be done away with completely. Luckily, class-based applications have a built-in mechanism to handle data storage - it's the `self` variable.

See below for a working example. The questions' `IntVar()` objects are associated with each individual class instance, so the class's internal behavior will reference the correct `IntVar()` value. Refer to the lines declaring `self.q1 = IntVar()` - the `self.` statement assigns that `IntVar()` to the class instance and persists the variable as a class member after the `Configure` method completes. This way, the value of `q1` is easily accessed and updated for each separate page, instead of being overwritten for each question being added.

```
import tkinter as tk

#a single frame with a question and multiple options
class Question(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *options, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *options, **kwargs)
        # global self1
        # self1 = self

    def Configure(self, *options, **keywords):
        print("-" * 40)
        questionframe=tk.Frame(self)
        questionframe.pack(side="top", fill="x")        
        for kw in keywords:
            if kw == "question":
                tk.Label(questionframe, text=keywords[kw]).pack(anchor=tk.W)
                print(keywords[kw])
        print("-" * 40)
        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        # global v
        self.v = tk.IntVar() #variable for keeping track of radiobuttons
        Buttons = []
        i = 1
        for option in options:
            b = tk.Radiobutton(buttonframe, text=option, variable=self.v, 
value=i)
            b.pack(anchor=tk.W)
            Buttons.append(b)
            i += 1
            print(option)
        return Buttons

    #return the index of the selected radiobutton (starts from 1)
    def GetSelectedIndex(self):
        return self.v.get()

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()

class Page1(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def ButtonPress():
            print("Selected Option:", self.q1.GetSelectedIndex())
        # global q1
        self.q1 = Question(self)
        self.q1.Configure("Car", "Minecart", "Riding a spider", "Flight",
            question="How would you prefer to get around?")
        self.q1.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(self, command=ButtonPress, text="press me - 1").pack()
   def GetSelectedIndex(self):
        return self.q1.GetSelectedIndex()

class Page2(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def ButtonPress():
            print("Selected Option:", self.q1.GetSelectedIndex())
        # global q1
        self.q1 = Question(self)
        self.q1.Configure("Day", "Night",
        question="Do you prefer day or night time?")
        self.q1.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        tk.Button(self, command=ButtonPress, text="press me - 2").pack()
   def GetSelectedIndex(self):
        return self.q1.GetSelectedIndex()

CurrentPage = 0
MaxPages = 1
def ChangePage(amount):
    global CurrentPage
    CurrentPage += amount
    CurrentPage = sorted((0, CurrentPage, MaxPages))[1]
    print("Current Page: " + str(CurrentPage))
    return CurrentPage

class MainView(tk.Frame):     
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        def On_Back():
            ChangePage(-1)
            Pages[CurrentPage].lift()
        def On_Next():
            ChangePage(1)
            Pages[CurrentPage].lift()
        def GetP1Value():
            print("Selected Option:", Pages[0].GetSelectedIndex())

        #the correct value is output when Page2(self) is removed
        Pages = [Page1(self), Page2(self)]

        Frame_Buttons = tk.Frame(self)
        Frame_Buttons.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", expand=False)
        Button_Next = tk.Button(Frame_Buttons, text="Next", 
command=On_Next).pack(side="right")
        Button_Back = tk.Button(Frame_Buttons, text="Back", 
command=On_Back).pack(side="right")
        tk.Button(Frame_Buttons, text="get page 1", 
command=GetP1Value).pack(side="right")
        Frame_Pages = tk.Frame(self)
        Frame_Pages.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        for page in Pages:
            page.place(in_=Frame_Pages, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        Pages[0].show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("300x300")
    root.mainloop()
```